# Write a search result of a data frame into a new column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I guess that this is one of the easiest tasks, but I have no idea how to do it.
I have a data.frame with a lot of data, a receipt number with an account number to which it was expensed.

```
ACCOUNT RECEIPT
10000   2121
12000   1515
21000   2121
50200   1515
47500   1474
90000   1474
```

I now want to search for the first receipt number and list all account numbers in a new column. I am currently not sure if the result should also list the account of the current receip, because one can see it anyway.

```
ACCOUNT RECEIPT RESULT
  10000    2121 21000        
  12000    1515 50200
  21000    2121 10000
  50200    1515 12000
  47500    1474 90000, 140000
  90000    1474 47500, 140000
 140000    1474 47500, 90000
```

I really like to use dplyr, maybe it is already possible to do it with it, I just can't see the solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need multiple rows for each `RECEIPT` in your final table.
I'd propose this solution

```
library(dplyr)

dt = read.table(text="ACCOUNT RECEIPT
10000   2121
12000   1515
21000   2121
50200   1515
47500   1474
90000   1474", header=T)

dt %>%
  group_by(RECEIPT) %>%
  summarise(ALL_ACCOUNTS = paste(ACCOUNT, collapse = ", "))

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   RECEIPT ALL_ACCOUNTS
#     <int>        <chr>
# 1    1474 47500, 90000
# 2    1515 12000, 50200
# 3    2121 10000, 21000
```

Where, as you mentioned, you get one row for each `RECEIPT` value and then all corresponding `ACCOUNT` values.

To achieve exactly what you mentioned in your question try this

```
library(dplyr)

dt = read.table(text="ACCOUNT RECEIPT
                10000   2121
                12000   1515
                21000   2121
                50200   1515
                47500   1474
                90000   1474
                140000  1474", header=T)

dt %>%
  left_join(dt, by="RECEIPT") %>%            # join same dataset to get all combinations of accounts
  filter(ACCOUNT.x != ACCOUNT.y) %>%         # filter out cases with same account numbers
  group_by(ACCOUNT.x, RECEIPT) %>%           # group by pairs of first account number and receipt
  summarise(REST_ACCOUNTS = paste(ACCOUNT.y, collapse = ", ")) %>%   # combine rest of account numbers
  ungroup() %>%                              # forget the grouping
  arrange(RECEIPT) %>%                       # order by receipt (only if needed for better visualisation)
  rename(ACCOUNT = ACCOUNT.x)                # change the name (only if needed for better visualisation)

# # A tibble: 7 x 3
#   ACCOUNT RECEIPT REST_ACCOUNTS
#     <int>   <int>         <chr>
# 1   47500    1474 90000, 140000
# 2   90000    1474 47500, 140000
# 3  140000    1474  47500, 90000
# 4   12000    1515         50200
# 5   50200    1515         12000
# 6   10000    2121         21000
# 7   21000    2121         10000
```

Comment: This looks very good. If I would need multiple rows, is it possible to get an output similar to my example. I could use rbind to merge your and my table, but maybe there is an easier solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: EXACTLY your solution is not possible, as you haven't included the account number 140000 in the first table! :-) But a similar one should be possible...